# Discard Matching Rows and Keep Unmatched Rows T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rows, matching

I have a data set and trying to come up with a SQL query to keep unmatched rows and discard matched rows.

```
X_ID    Y_ID    Client_Id   User_Id date    
-------------------------------------------------------------
NULL    3000547 10000593    2001284 2019-03-11 10:59:21.214 X_ID <> Y_ID for Same Client_ID & User_ID so I want to keep these records.
NULL    3000547 10000593    2001284 2019-03-11 10:45:09.022 
NULL    3000547 10000593    2001284 2019-03-11 19:29:30.028 
NULL    3000547 10000593    2001284 2019-03-11 19:29:45.168 
NULL    3000547 10000593    2001284 2019-03-11 11:06:12.072 
NULL    NULL    10000622    2000576 2019-03-27 09:33:42.995 
NULL    NULL    10000622    2000576 2019-03-27 09:34:04.495 
NULL    NULL    10000622    2000576 2019-03-27 15:53:48.794 
NULL    NULL    10000622    2018815 2019-03-27 10:37:01.250 
4000954 4000954 10157846    2017957 2019-03-11 13:44:54.469 X_ID = Y_ID for Same Client_ID & User_ID so I want to discard these records.
4000954 4000954 10157846    2017957 2019-03-11 13:30:35.101 
4000954 4000954 10157846    2017957 2019-03-11 13:33:23.738 
4000954 4000954 10157846    2017957 2019-03-14 16:25:24.684 
4000954 4000954 10157846    2017957 2019-03-14 16:25:24.684 
4000954 4000954 10157846    2017957 2019-03-14 16:25:24.684 
4000954 4000954 10157846    2017957 2019-03-14 08:52:32.047 
4000954 4000954 10157846    2017957 2019-03-27 15:02:30.867 
4000954 4000954 10462731    2017957 2019-03-27 15:57:12.415 
4000954 NULL    10761202    2017957 2019-03-29 12:36:16.546 X_ID <> Y_ID for Same Client_ID & User_ID so I want to keep these records.
NULL    4000954 10792367    2000876 2019-03-25 16:22:33.457 
NULL    4000954 10792367    2001469 2019-03-29 13:54:25.354 
4000954 NULL    12312028    2017957 2019-03-29 12:35:47.140 
4000954 4000761 12642798    2017957 2019-03-25 16:18:19.522 There is one match of X_ID = Y_ID for same Clieny_ID & User_ID so I want to discard all three rows. 
4000954 4000954 12642798    2017957 2019-03-25 16:18:19.522 
4000954 4000954 12642798    2017957 2019-03-25 16:18:19.522 
4000954 4000761 12642798    2017957 2019-03-25 16:18:19.522 All the rows X_ID <> Y_ID for Same Client_id & User_ID so I want to keep these records
4000954 4000762 12642798    2017957 2019-03-25 16:18:19.522 
4000954 4000763 12642798    2017957 2019-03-25 16:18:19.522
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT Distinct Client_ID, User_ID
    FROM [Your_Table]
    WHERE X_ID = Y_ID
)

SELECT *
FROM [Your_Table] AS T
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE AS C
    ON T.Client_ID = C.Client_ID
    AND T.User_ID = C.User_ID
WHERE C.Client_ID IS NULL
AND C.User_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: The CTE will select all the Client_IDs and User_IDs that have matching X_ID and Y_ID (even if a single record is matching). In the query, I am just selecting the records that are not from CTE. In a way, filtering out client_IDs and User_IDs that have matching X_IDs and Y_IDs. I hope I am not missing anything and the query helps.

Comment: thank you, it worked and really appreciate your help. I will continue working on it to make sure all the cases are covered.

Comment: @Ally If the answer worked for you then please mark it as accepted. Check [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT X_ID, Y_ID, Client_Id, User_Id
FROM your_table
```